# Java ME alternative for Raspberry Pi programming

Tags: java-me, embedded

I want to start with embedded system programming with the raspberry pi. I just want to do build basic electrical control systems, e.g. controlling servo motors, etc. I had a look around and because I have been mostly doing high-level programmin, I thought Java ME would be the best option - unfortunately Java ME 3.3 is only available on Windows and I'm currently working on OS X.

My question what would be a good alternativ for Java ME? With Java ME I don't just mean the API, but also testing/emulation options. I guess it's going to be something in C/C++, which isn't a problem (even though I'm not as familiar with the languages), but I have no idea where to look/start. Do you have any good suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The de-facto OS for Raspberry Pi is Linux, so you have a wide choice.  Python is well supported on Raspberry Pi, with libraries to support the GPIO.  C and C++ are equally well supported, though less talked about in the RPI community. C and C++ are on the other hand the most common languages used in embedded systems in general since they are systems level languges that do not rely on an OS, VM or interpreter to run.

While you might learn something about what the Raspberry Pi Foundation like to call "Physical Computing" (interfacing with the outside world), it is not an ideal platform for embedded systems development in general - it is very little I/O and you will probably need an I/O expander such as the GertBoard.

RPi development differs from most embedded development in that on an RPi you can develop on the target, whereas in embedded development it is more common to cross-compile on a development host.  In that sense RPi development is little different than developing for a desktop Linux computer with an I/O board.

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer! Do you know any good resources for C/C++ Raspberry Pi development? E.g. settings a virtual environment, adding correct libraries and so on?

Comment: Since RPi runs Linux, any resourced for Linux development and GCC are relevant. Specific RPi stuff of interst might be found in [The MagPi](http://www.themagpi.com/) on-line magazine.

Answer (score 1):

If Java is what you want to use, you can use Java SE on the pi.

What is best is a philosophical question that can have no universal answer.

Edit: you may also find this Raspeberry Pi GPIO solution interesting:

http://pi4j.com/example/control.html

Comment: Dose Java SE feature all the needed APIs for accessing and writing to I/O interfaces, like the GPIO port?

Comment: You can do that with the GPIO sysfs nodes accessed from java as "files".  Given that jni is possible you can ultimately do anything you could do from C in terms of interacting with other interfaces (though running a jvm as the superuser is something you want to think about very carefully before doing).  If you are going to do a lot of / mostly low level work, Java might not be the best fit.

Answer (score -1):

You can install **[Lazarus](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Lazarus_on_Raspberry_Pi)** and start coding immediately.

Comment: I would really appreciate if there comes an explanation for downvoting, since I use Lazarus to develop RPi applications which control various custom made electronic devices, and I recommend it as "Java ME alternative for Raspberry Pi programming", which was the topic. I would really alike to know how come that Lazarus does not fit into that?